# How to call a rake task inside controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I call a rake task in an controller?

I need it to a delayed job.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341). Why do you think need to run a rake task from the controller?

Comment: I think I need to run a rake task in the controller to run it as a delayed job.

Comment: What are you using to manage your delayed jobs?

Comment: It is my first delayed job and I dont know have I should manage it

Comment: Are you using a gem or plugin?

Comment: I am using the gem delayed_job

Comment: Delayed Job doesn't require a rake task to queue or run jobs. Have you read the [README](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)?

Comment: Yes I have read the readme. How do I then run a rake task as a delayed job every 15 minutes

Comment: Delayed job isn't suitable for that. You want cron or something like it. There's a ruby gem called clockwork, for instance.

Comment: Should then move my code in my in my rake file to the controller to create a delayed job?

Comment: Hmm, you should put your code in your delayed job class. But it sounds like you have some confusion how all of these pieces fit together. It would be easier if you gave us some context -- what are you trying to accomplish at a functional level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Rake::Task['task_name'].invoke(args)
```

But, I'd recommend against this; it's bad practice. It's better to either use Cron if you need that type of functionality, or you can use delayed_job with a custom job object specific to your needs. I'd personally recommend the latter as it causes less pain when moving servers. But delayed_job is not built to run rake tasks, it's meant to queue work items that you create.

Comment: You will need to put in another line, " require 'rake' " or you will get "uninitialized constant YourController::Rake".  This can be handy for testing, but not generally used in Production.

Answer (score 0):

If you need cron jobs within Ruby I *highly* recommend the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)